# listing the object of a bucket works through boto, but throws error through boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to list the objects of a bucket.
I used the following code in boto and it worked fine

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.connection import OrdinaryCallingFormat
from boto.s3.key import Key

destination = S3Connection(aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key='lokesh', is_secure=False, port=9090, host=host, calling_format=OrdinaryCallingFormat())
destination_bucket = destination.get_bucket(bucket_name)

destination_all_keys = destination_bucket.get_all_keys()
print destination_all_keys
for key in destination_all_keys:
    print key
```

However if I am using boto3, then I am getting error

botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MethodNotAllowed) when calling the ListObjects operation: The specified method is not allowed against this resource.

below is the boto3 code that gives error

```
import boto3
destination = boto3.client('s3',
                    endpoint_url=endpoint,
                    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
                    use_ssl=False,
                    config=timeout_config
                    )

destination.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name)['Contents']
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is in boto3 is using [boto3 session](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/core/session.html) .

```
import boto3
sess = boto3.session(
    endpoint_url=endpoint,
    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
    use_ssl=False,
    config=timeout_config)

s3 = sess.client("s3")
s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name)
```

In addition, passing API key is a bad design. If you deploy application into any AWS services that use IAM roles, the accesskey lines will give you headache.

Just setup your local .aws credential file and you can use simple setup such as this.

```
import boto3
sess = boto3.session(
        endpoint_url=endpoint,
        use_ssl=False,
        config=timeout_config)

    s3 = sess.client("s3")
    s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name)
```

Comment: I tried using session, but instead I got the error 

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

seems like boto3.session is not callable

Comment: @user3463896 : i. Always use `virtualenv` or `conda` virtual development environment. ii. Update your boto3 using `pip install boto3 --upgrade`